# Return array from INDEX function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, quantlib

I'm trying to use INDEX in array format in Excel but I'm running into problems.

From this question: [Return array from INDEX function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868867/return-array-from-index-function), it seems that "INDEX (like VLOOKUP) doesn't return an array of values (except in some convoluted circumstances)"

So I'm wondering what alternatives there are.

I'm trying to do this:

```
=qlTimeSeries( ,
               INDEX({39618,39619,39638,39639},{2,3,4}),
               INDEX({18,19,38,39},{2,3,4})
               )
```

and Index is not returning an array.

Any alternative idea how to get the result I am trying to get with INDEX({39618,39619,39638,39639},{2,3,4})?
i.e. from {39618,39619,39638,39639} get {39619,39638,39639} back?

NOTE: Instead of INDEX({39618,39619,39638,39639},{2,3,4}) my spreadsheet in fact uses a dynamic array of dates and the objective is to drop the first element of the array {39618,39619,39638,39639} which is why I am using INDEX.

EDIT: Looking for a solution that avoids using VBA

Comment: if the dates are in the sheet, you can use INDEX as `ref` for start and end. like: `=INDEX(A:A,3):INDEX(A:A,7)` would be the range (A3:A7). But if the values are generated inside the array, it will be easier to change your formula ore use VBA as you would need the whole array to get the `{39618,39619,39638,39639}` multiple times inside the formula

Comment: the dates are not in the sheet, they come from a formula. I am trying to avoid VBA, would like to do it using formulas only.

The full formula is INDEX(qlTimeSeriesDates(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&qlTimeSeriesSize(A1)))) where A1 is a handle and ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&qlTimeSeriesSize(A1))) is just {2;3;4;...;N}

Comment: then either go for helper-cells or use a completely different approach or use vba...

Comment: Only if the order is always like your example (`{smallest number, < x1 <, < x2 <, biggest number}`) then you could use something like: `SMALL({39618,39619,39638,39639},{2,3,4})`...

Comment: thank you. this first index function i use will always be ordered (i.e. INDEX({39618,39619,39638,39639},{2,3,4})) but the second one (INDEX({18,19,38,39},{2,3,4})) will not necessarily.
the elements {2,3,4} to be extracted will always be the same though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
= INDEX({39618,39619,39638,39639},N(IF({1},{2,3,4})))
```

This will return what you desire: `{39619,39638,39639}`.

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard after typing this formula instead of just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(Also note this works with dynamic ranges, not just hard-coded arrays.)

Comment: @jsamler Please mark this answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Comment: Clever, I didn't even know of the `N()` formula... Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Is the use of the `If({1},{2,3,4})` needed there, or could you write it as `N({2,3,4})`? It seems like removing the if statement allows the same behavior.